# How do I create generator function that can be used multiple times in a postman request?

Tags: javascript, rest, templates, request, postman

I want to create a function that is used inside a request body.

Every time the function is called, it returns a different value; a number that increases by 1 every time that it is called.

I want to call this function multiple times inside a postman request in order to insert a sequence of numbers throughout the request body.

e.g.

```
{
    "first": {nextSequenceNumber()},
    "second": {nextSequenceNumber()},
    "third": {nextSequenceNumber()},
    "fourth": {nextSequenceNumber()},
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it "just work" exactly as you've written it? What's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could build the object as javascript in a declarative style with inline invocations.

```
let response = {body: {
"first": {nextSequenceNumber()},
"second": {nextSequenceNumber()},
"third": {nextSequenceNumber()},
"fourth": {nextSequenceNumber()}}};

response.body.someField = ‘foo’(
```

In your return block (using express.js etc.), send the JS object you built.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) function and take the value property of the `next` call.

```js
function* getNext(i) {
    while (true) yield i++;
}

var sequenceNumber = getNext(0),
    object = {
        first: sequenceNumber.next().value,
        second: sequenceNumber.next().value,
        third: sequenceNumber.next().value,
        fourth: sequenceNumber.next().value
    };

console.log(object);
```

The same wrapped in a closure

```js
function* getNext(i) {
    while (true) yield i++;
}

var sequenceNumber = (gen => gen.next().value)(getNext(0)),
    object = {
        first: sequenceNumbert(),
        second: sequenceNumber(),
        third: sequenceNumber(),
        fourth: sequenceNumber()
    };

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible hacky way of doing it but it would give you an object that looked like this:

```
{  
   "first":1,
   "second":2,
   "third":3,
   "forth":4
}
```

If you added this to the `Pre-Request Script` of your Request:

```
var n = 0;
function increment() { return ++n; }

function requestBody(first, second, third, forth) {
  this.first    = first
  this.second   = second
  this.third    = third
  this.forth    = forth
}

let myData = new requestBody(increment(), increment(), increment(), increment())
pm.globals.set('bodyData', JSON.stringify(myData))
```

You could just use the `{{bodyData}}` variable as the body of the request:

[image: Postman]

Again, its not a very good solution but it *might* be something to iterate on.